# Intercept @RequestBody after serialization but before controller

Tags: spring-mvc

My request body objects all implement a interface call Auditable, where the username and lastUpdate timestamp could be set.  I would like to intercept calls to controller functions after serialization but before it hits controller so can I can these values in a single place.

I looked at `HandlerInterceptor.prehandle` but this method executes before serialization.  Any suggestion on how I can make this happen?

Comment: you are really fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ControllerAdvice and it can help in these scenarios. It intercepts all controller requests and you can access the serialized domain object in the method. It can pretty much all args that a requestMapping method takes. Hope this helps.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model, @RequestBody DomainObject domain) {
        domain.setUserName("test");
        // set other items that you want to do.
    }   

}
```